# Expose node_module using both import and require

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I wrote a node module and I'm trying to understand how I would go about allowing users to either require or import the module depending on their environment.

At the moment I'm exposing my classes like this:

**/src/index.ts**

```
import { Class1 }  from './Class1';
import { Class2 } from './Class2 ';

module.exports = {
    Class1,
    Class2
}
```

gets compiled to

**/lib/index.js**

```
var Class1_1 = require("./Class1")
var Class2_1 = require("./Class2 ")

module.exports = {
  Class1: Class1_1.Class1
  Class2: Class2_1.Class2
}
```

which works allows require but not import

```
const { Class1, Class2 } = require('my-module');
```

I've been googling everything I can think of but can't get any examples or pointers.

Comment: Save the file using `node --experimental-modules my-app.mjs` and you could be able to acces files using `import.`

Comment: I have an `my-app.ts` file that I'm using for testing and it says **Module ''../node_modules/my-module/lib"' has no exported member 'Class1'.**. Typscript should be able to import the above exports though right (the same as node expiremental)?